# Data source name not found and no default driver specified (ODBC)

Tags: asp.net, mysql, wpf, odbc

**Hi,**

I have a ASP.NET webapplication where I use ODBCConnection to connect a MySQL server, it will take the connectionstring from the web.config file and this works grate.

But when I put the same code in a WPF application and hardcode the same connection string I get the followin exception when runnint ODBCConnection.Open() :

**Data source name not found and no default driver specified**

I have checked the ODBCConnection orbject and its instansiated with the exact same connectionstring as in the webapplication.

The connection string looks like this :

**"DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=X.X.X.X;DATABASE=X;USER=X;PASSWORD=X;OPTION=3"**

*The X is set to propert values*

I am running both from the same computer so the MYSQL ODBC connection is installed correct.

Pleas advice.

**BestRegards**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by changing the Building for CPU from Any to x86 on thw WPF application.